# User ID parameter in Laravel Request

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have an admin where he is able to create and update users. I made a new Form request called `UserUpdateRequest`. How can I pass the user id so that it can update user detail? Here are my rules:

```php
// UserUpdateRequest 
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'firstname' => 'required|min:2|max:255',
        'lastname' => 'required|min:2|max:255',
        'username' => 'required|max:255',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,email,????',
        'contact' => 'required|integer',
        'gender' => 'required|in:m,f',
        'role_id' => 'required|exists:roles,id',
    ];
}

// Controller
public function update(UserUpdateRequest $request, User $user)
{
    $user->update([
        'firstname' => request('firstname'),
        'lastname' => request('lastname'),
        'username' => request('username'),
        'email' => request('email'),
        'contact' => request('contact'),
        'gender' => request('gender'),
        'role_id' => request('role_id'),
    ]);

    session()->flash('message', 'User has been successfully added.');

    return redirect('/users/' . $user->id);
}
```

`'required|email|max:255|unique:users,email,????',` is where I am confused.

Comment: check this. it will help [https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/laravel-5-validation-request-how-to-handle-validation-on-update](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/laravel-5-validation-request-how-to-handle-validation-on-update)

Answer (score 7):

Here's what i did:

View:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{ $user->id }}" name="user_id">
```

Controller:

```
public function rules()
    {
        $id = $this->request->get('user_id');

    return [
        'firstname' => 'required|min:2|max:255',
        'lastname' => 'required|min:2|max:255',
        'username' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,email,'.$id,
        'contact' => 'required|integer',
        'gender' => 'required|in:m,f',
        'role_id' => 'required|exists:roles,id',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/user/edit/{id}', 'UserController@edit')->name('user.edit');
Route::post('/user/update/{id}', 'UserController@update')->name('user.update');
```

FormRequest

```
'email' => ['required',Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this->route('id'))],
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 3):

Since admin is changing users I assume you already have user data on your view file.

you can pass a hidden input on your form.

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{$user->id}}" name="user_id" />
```

and then receive it on your controller.

```
$user_id = $request->input('user_id');
$user = \App\User::find($user_id); 
//validation comes here
```

**Edit Depending on new information**

```
public function update(UserUpdateRequest $request, User $user)
```

should be

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
```

and you have to call Request on your controller;

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

after that you can get your request as

```
dd($request->all());
```

but if you are using a special request post your **UserUpdateRequest** class.

Comment: My problem is how do i pass the parameter into the Form Request in order for me to query the 'user_id' that im going to edit

Comment: $user = User::find($id); 
return::view('yourview')->with('user',$user); but in that case you will ask me how do I get id to current view lol. You need to learn how to pass data to views and recieve special data from views. Check Laravel responses and routes documentation its pretty well written there

Comment: Here's what i did:

Comment: The user id should still be checked by some kind of validation/middleware as the user can edit the hidden field to another user id and do stuff he's not supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the userId as in hidden input field and use in the unique validation like

```
unique:users,email,userId
```

Comment: how to pass the user id in the Form Request?

Comment: As a form element <input type="hidden" value="{{$user->id}}" name="userId" />

Comment: if you are editing a user then you must have the id of the editing user, just pass the same thing in the form.

Comment: Yes but how can i pass it into my form request?? i created a new form request.